# Anonymous class error c++ macbook Sodoma 14.4

Tags: xcode, class, anonymous

I am trying to run a python script which includes a wrapper for a c++ code.
The script runs on a linux machine without any issues.
When I compile the c++ part with make, it throws me this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__filesystem/path.h:446:1: fatal error: declaration of anonymous class must be a definition
class _LIBCPP_EXPORTED_FROM_ABI path {
^
1 error generated.
```

Can anybody help me with fixing this?
Thanks!

I tried re-installing both the Command Line Tools and XCode but nothing seems to work.
I do not have any anaconda/brew/ports installed.